# Where are the options settings in Chrome stored

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

Does any one know where the "Options" settings for chrome are stored?

Can they be transferred to another PC ?

Comment: They are stored in multiple files in the User Data directory. You’ll need to copy them all or else be more specific about which option you want to export.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows XP they are stored in:

> C:\Documents and Settings[user]\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

in a file called `Preferences` (no extension).

I don't see why you can't copy this from one profile to another - just back up the existing file first.

However, there's the sync options in:

> chrome://settings/personal

[image: Google Chrome sync options]

which allow you sync everything anyway - you do need to have a Google account to do this.

Comment: I tried preferences and it did not seem to carry over settings. I get a "chrome did not shut down correctly" when I open chrome for the first time after copying the file. I am having trouble adding a new search engine to "manage search engines" I thought I could migrate that setting, I guess not.

Comment: Figured it out, seems they changed the requirement for the keyword. it must contain .com, .net, etc. It did not when I first set it up on an older version, you could use any set of letters or numbers.